# Convert a comma-delimited list of full names into an array

Tags: php, string

I have a string such as:
Crosby Bing, Gretzky Wayne, Clemente Roberto

I would like to have the string converted to an array so it looks like:

```
LName[0]=>Crosby 
FName[0]=>Bing, 
LName[1]=>Gretzky 
FName[1]=>Wayne, 
LName[2]=>Clemente 
FName[2]=>Roberto
```

I am terrible with arrays and string manipulation and have done many searches on the web but can't locate the appropriate solution.

I look forward to your response!

Comment: Then you might want to read: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Wow, how many people misunderstood the question completely?

Comment: Do you need those trailing commas included in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
<?php

$LName = array();
$FName = array();

list($LName[0],$FName[0],$LName[1],$FName[1],$LName[2],$FName[2]) = 
      explode(" ","Crosby Bing, Gretzky Wayne, Clemente Roberto");

print_r($LName);

print_r($FName);

?>
```

demo: http://codepad.org/g4YnwKxW

Or if your list is dynamic:

```
<?php

    $LName = array();
    $FName = array();

    $fullNames = 
          explode(", ","Crosby Bing, Gretzky Wayne, Clemente Roberto");

    foreach($fullNames as $full){
         list($LName[], $FName[]) = explode(" ", $full);
    }

    print_r($LName);

    print_r($FName);

    ?>
```

demo: http://codepad.org/WMIx9mJD

Comment: @Felix, i was taught never to *assume*

Comment: @Neal: This approach is difficult to maintain as you must constantly worry about having the right number of array elements in the list. Also, what if the number of names is not known, e.g., they come from a database?

Comment: @Neal: If you see a comma-separated string, you should _never_ assume, that this is static ;)

Comment: While you're not assuming the string is dynamic, you're assuming it's constant.

Comment: @Neal: Well, then lets not call it assume, but you should be able to **abstract** from a *specific* example to the *general* problem.

Comment: @Neal: OP even said *such as*.

Comment: The data string, yes dynamic, can be any quantity of Fname and Lname pairs, but there will always be pairs. There could be 1 pair, up to perhaps 40 total.

Comment: @Papdog, yes, that is what my edit fixed, look at the second part about a `dynamic list`

Comment: The proposed dynamic example works wonderfully, thank you Neal.

Comment: I selected your dynamic solution as my accepted answer. Thanks again Neal

Answer (score 2):

```
$nameString = 'Crosby Bing, Gretzky Wayne, Clemente Roberto';
$names = array_map('trim', explode(',', $nameString));

foreach ($names as &$name) {
  $name = explode(' ', $name, 2);
}
```

Its slightly different from what you want. Its an array of arrays, where the inner arrays has 2 values with the first one the first and the second value is the second (and any further) name. It should not be difficult to convert it into your structure, if even required.

```
echo $name[0][0]; // Crosby
echo $name[0][1]; // Bing
```

Kevin Peno suggest something like this in the comments below

```
$nameString = 'Crosby Bing, Gretzky Wayne, Clemente Roberto';

foreach (explode(',',$nameString) as &$name) {
  $name = explode(' ', trim($name), 2);
}
```

However, they both are semantic equivalent and as long as there are not 1M names in the string (which will also consumes "1M * average-string-length Byte" of memory), I dont think anyone may realise any performance difference.

Comment: If you are going to `foreach`, you may as well do away with the `array_map` (or vice versa).

Comment: It's not equivilant. You are looping 2 times in your version. By running one `foreach` or `array_map` on the outer `explode` you are looping once. Even performance aside, it is easier to see what is going on. Why break it out?

Answer (score 1):

Done in one line!

```
preg_match_all('/(\w+) (\w+)(?:, )?/', "Crosby Bing, Gretzky Wayne, Clemente Roberto", $a);

/*
    $fName = $a[1];
    $lName = $a[2];
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) can be useful.

Example:

*Things used:* 
[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) 
[`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

```
$name = 'Crosby Bing';
$splittedName = explode(' ', $name);

var_dump($splittedName);
```

Should return:

```
[0] => 'Crosby',
[1] => 'Bing'
```

---

And splitting list of names is just simple loop:

Things used: 
[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) 
[foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) 
[reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

```
$names = 'Crosby Bing, Gretzky Wayne, Clemente Roberto';
$namesArray = explode(',', $names);

foreach($names as &$name)
{
    $name = explode(' ', trim($name));
}
```

And simple function:

*Things used:*
[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) 
[Function creation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) 
[`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) 
[`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
function GetNames($name)
{
    $names = explode(' ', $name);
    $namesCount = count($names);

    $data = array();
    $data['Names']  = array_slice($names, 0, $namesCount - 2);
    $data['Surname'] = $names[$namesCount - 1];

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two operations. First to split the initial string into an array of names and then work through that array and split each name into firstname and lastname.

The following code shows that but works only under the premise that a full name contains only of a firstname and lastname and both are sperated by a single space.

```
$allNames = 'Crosby Bing, Gretzky Wayne, Clemente Roberto'; // your string
$names = explode(', ', $allNames); // create an array with all names
$LName = $FName = array(); // initialize your result arrays
foreach($names as $name) {
    list($firstName, lastName) = explode(' ', $name, 2); // split each name apart
    $FName[] = $firstName; // add first name to result array
    $LName[] = $lastName; // add last name to result array
}
```

[Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is your friend here ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function, like so:

```
$names_string  = "Crosby Bing, Gretzky Wayne, Clemente Roberto";
$names = explode(",", $names_string);
echo $names[0]; // displays Crosby Bing
echo $names[1]; // displays Gretzky Wayne
```

Answer (score 0):

**Demo**

http://codepad.org/P4vSIgKP

**Code**

```
$str = 'Crosby Bing, Gretzky Wayne, Clemente Roberto';
$arr1=explode(',', $str);

foreach ($arr1 as $item){
   $arr2 = explode(' ', trim($item));
   $lname[]=$arr2[0];
   $fname[]=$arr2[1];       
}

print_r($lname);
print_r($fname);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Crosby
    [1] => Gretzky
    [2] => Clemente
)
Array
(
    [0] => Bing
    [1] => Wayne
    [2] => Roberto
```